# Facebook comments plugin working but 3rd level replies disappear when submitted

Tags: html, facebook, comments

I've implemented Facebook comments on my website here:

https://nonzerosum.games/kindnessequation.html

I'm using the designated script

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v19.0" nonce="kUZaWVcr"></script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://nonzerosum.games/kindnessequation.html" data-width="" data-numposts="25"></div>
```

The comments section is appearing fine but when anyone tries to add a reply to a reply to a comment (so two indents) when they submit the reply it vanishes and is lost. Not great for stimulating discussion. In order to comment they need to reply to the original comment, then the reply submits correctly, but everyone is getting caught out.

Can anyone tell me what to do to fix this? I have run tests without my css, and without other scripts in the file. I haven't seen any other questions specifically about this problem, so I assume it's not the plugin itself.